# How do I use packages installed from npm in my Laravel app?

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-10

I have tried to install multiple different packages and I have failed every time. Let's say I want to add the [Wysimark editor](https://www.wysimark.com/) to my project. I run `npm i --save @wysimark/standalone` as described in the documentation. Next, in `resources/js/app.js`, I add this line:

```
import { createWysimark } from "@wysimark/standalone";
```

But what do I do next? When I try to use the `createWysimark()` function in my Laravel view, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: createWysimark is not defined`. Should I include the `app.js` file into the page somehow? But how? I can't use its path, since it is in the `resources` folder, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually build your assets after importing them. Take a look into your *package.json* inside your root folder. For development it's usually `npm run development` but may differ depending on your package.json

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have done that (it was `npm run build`) and now I have a new folder `build` in my `public` folder. This folder contains `manifest.json` and `assets` folder containing two `app-[some_hash].js` files, one for `app.css` and one for `app.js`. What should I do next? When I include one of these JS files into my view, I still get the error.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I was also missing this line in my `app.js`: `window.createWysimark = createWysimark;`. Now that I've added it and built again, it works!